# How is this asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new to node.js and asynchronous JS and I'm not sure if I interpret it correctly. I'm trying to understand how this chunk of code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var filedir = process.argv[2]

function doneReading(err, fileContents) {
    var lines = fileContents.split("\n")
    console.log(lines.length-1)
}
function countLines(filedir) {
    fs.readFile(filedir, "utf8", doneReading)
}
countLines(filedir)
```

is asynchronous?
Is it because I can call *countLines* function multiple times, each time with different *filedir* argument, so it prints out length of the file? I mean.. how is that asynchronous? Isn't that just how functions work?

Comment: If you add a `console.log()` immediately after the call to `countLines()` you'll see that its output is printed **before** the count of lines. That's because the system doesn't call your `doneReading()` function until the process of reading the file (asynchronously) is finished.

Comment: It is asynchronous because `fs.readFile` is asynchronous.

Comment: The `readFileSync` is a synchronous version of the method, which *sometimes* makes sense to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is asynchronous. But it is not asynchronous because you called `countLines()` multiple times. It is asynchronous because you did asynchronous function call at:
`fs.readFile(filedir, "utf8", doneReading);`

This function is not going to block your process. It is called asynchronously. After you call the function, the control does not wait for the function to finish synchronously but continues with the remaining code. When the file is loaded, your **callback function** is called. Put a `console.log("I run first")` after your `countlines()` function call and feed a very large file to your script. You can see the console logs the **I run first** before your file content is loaded. But if you use the `fs.readFileSync()` the synchronous alternative, and put a `console.log()` and log something after the function call, you will see the script waits till the whole file is read and only then logs your log.

Asynchronous functions usually have this pattern:

```
yourAsyncCall(arg1,arg2,...,callbackFunction);
```

You see `callbackFunction()` can be implicitly defined as anonymous function like in Oliver's answer or defined somewhere else like your example. It has this convention of `error` as first argument and your result from the callback(if no error occurs) as second argument. As you can see in

```
function doneReading(err, fileContents);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is asynchronous.

It's merely using a named function instead of an anonymous function.

Based on this the code could be re-written like so:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var filedir = process.argv[2]

function countLines(filedir) {
    fs.readFile(filedir, "utf8", function(err, fileContents) {
        var lines = fileContents.split("\n")
        console.log(lines.length-1)
    });
}
countLines(filedir)
```

Edit:

To expand on @squint's comment, the use of the synchronous variant of the readFile method is justifiable in cases where the *speed* of your nodejs application isn't of importance, due to the fact that a synchronous read command would cause the entire program to wait for the read operation to complete before continuing.